# Tkinter IntVar not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a mainframe class and then a 'inforow' class that fills info on the frame row by row but the StringVar and Intvar's dont seem to work. They are being set as the printout shows but the checkbutton doesn't reflect the value that they are being set to. I have made a simpler version that highlights the issue in these two files.

I am using 'Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32'

When I run mainframe.py all the checkbuttons are blank but I am expecting them to be a mix of set and unset.

mainframe.py

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import inforow

testinfo = {'ITEM 1': {'one':1, 'two':0, 'three':1}
    , 'ITEM 2': {'one':0, 'two':1, 'three':0}}

class MainFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, **options):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, **options)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.addHeader()
        self.addInfo(testinfo)

    def addHeader(self):
        Label(self, text="Item").grid(row=0,column=0)
        Label(self, text="one").grid(row=0,column=1)
        Label(self, text="two").grid(row=0,column=2)
        Label(self, text="three").grid(row=0,column=3)

    def addInfo(self, info):
        row = 1
        for item in info:
            inforow.InfoRow(self, row, item, info[item])
            row += 1

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    root = Tk()
    MainFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

and inforow.py

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class InfoRow():

    def __init__(self, root, row, item, values):
        self.chkUsedVar1 = IntVar()
        self.chkUsedVar1.set(values["one"])
        self.chkUsedVar2 = IntVar()
        self.chkUsedVar2.set(values["two"])
        self.chkUsedVar3 = IntVar()
        self.chkUsedVar3.set(values["three"])


        self.skillLabel = Label(root, width=10, text=item, anchor="w")
        self.skillLabel.grid(row=row,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.usedChkButton1 = Checkbutton(root, text='Used1', variable=self.chkUsedVar1)
        self.usedChkButton1.grid(row=row,column=1)

        self.usedChkButton2 = Checkbutton(root, text='Used2', variable=self.chkUsedVar2)
        self.usedChkButton2.grid(row=row,column=2)

        self.usedChkButton3 = Checkbutton(root, text='Used3', variable=self.chkUsedVar3)
        self.usedChkButton3.grid(row=row,column=3)
        print 'Row ' + item
        print self.chkUsedVar1.get()
        print self.chkUsedVar2.get()
        print self.chkUsedVar3.get()
        print
```

Comment: Can I suggest that if you are using Checkbuttons, you use BooleanVar instead of IntVar as it more closely fits with Checkbutton and also provides some use later on in understanding its purpose at a later date.

Comment: @SolarFactories - will do in future makes sense as just two states for the checkbutton. I have swapped the IntVars to BooleanVar but it still doesn't work for the test code :(

Comment: @SolarFactories: think it's perfectly fine to use Checkbuttons with integers or strings. There's a reason you're able to set the on and off values to anything, and not just boolean values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `IntVar`s are referenced only by the instance of your `InfoRow` class - and you do not keep any reference to that, so it all gets garbage collected immediately.  (Passing a var to `Checkbutton()` does not actually store a reference to the var, just its auto-generated name - `PY_VAR0` or whatever.)

If you completed this program, you'd obviously need to store the `InfoRow`s somewhere, so that you could retrieve the var values - and that would be enough to fix the Checkbuttons.

Comment: great stuff thank you very much just added a list to the MainFrame class and added the rows to the list as I create them and it now works and as you said when complete the program would have that - thanks again

Answer (score 0):

That was quite a lot of code. I had to reduce it to track down the issue. I found a symptom but I'm unable to see exactly how this should be done. It has something to do with the parent of Checkbutton. Examine my almost working code:

```
from tkinter import *

class MainFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        chk = IntVar()
        chk.set(1)
        used1 = Checkbutton(parent, text='Used1', variable=chk)
        used1.pack()
        print(self.winfo_children()[0])

root = Tk()
MainFrame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Now, this code results in the Checkbutton being checked, but the last line in the class, `print(self.winfo_children()[0])` generates an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qwerty\Documents\Python\test.py", line 15, in <module>
    MainFrame(root)
  File "C:\Users\qwerty\Documents\Python\test.py", line 12, in __init__
    print(self.winfo_children()[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I remove that line the error disappears, but also the checked state of the Checkbutton. I can't seem to understand this at the moment. I think I need a large coffee.

(I'm using Python 3.6.5 under win10)

Comment: I can't get your code to run in 2.7 without commenting out the winfo_children line out (no window appears) but not sure if this sheds any light on it but if you define an intvar outside of the class and pass it into MainFrames init it works then the checkbox then gets checked but I want the row class to contain the intvar as I want a method to report on the state of the row per row - if that makes sense

Comment: `self.winfo_children()[0]` is out of range because `self` *has no children* - you're adding the Checkbutton to `parent`, instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help figbeam - much appreciated